# how to generate thumbnail from video in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, video-thumbnails

we are doing a video record apps using Xamarin form .

my question is how to generate thumbnail from video in Xamarin form?

Comment: May you can tell which platforms you plan to support, Because any video recording/manipulation is very platform dependent.

Comment: we need to do it both ios ,and android platform

Answer (score 6):

On iOS you can do this:

```
public ImageSource GenerateThumbImage(string url, long usecond)
{      
    AVAssetImageGenerator imageGenerator = new AVAssetImageGenerator(AVAsset.FromUrl((new Foundation.NSUrl(url))));
    imageGenerator.AppliesPreferredTrackTransform = true;
    CMTime actualTime;
    NSError error;
    CGImage cgImage = imageGenerator.CopyCGImageAtTime(new CMTime(usecond, 1000000), out actualTime, out error);
    return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new     UIImage(cgImage).AsPNG().AsStream());mageSource.FromStream(() => new     UIImage(cgImage).AsPNG().AsStream());
}
```

On Android:

```
 public ImageSource GenerateThumbImage(string url, long usecond)
 {   
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.SetDataSource(url, new Dictionary<string, string>());
    Bitmap bitmap = retriever.GetFrameAtTime(usecond);
    if (bitmap != null)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
        byte[] bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
        return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bitmapData));
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Comment: The IOS code doesn't work. I'm getting the cgImage object back as (null)

Comment: on IOS, try to use - NSUrl.FromFilename (path) instead of -  new Foundation.NSUrl(url)